# Google Spreadsheets API Key example

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I'm developing an application which needs to access a "simple database" (Google spreadsheet) with users IDs.

I try with Oauth2.0 But that's not what I need.

I'm using this code to get access to the sheet:

```
    private static SheetsService AuthorizeGoogleApp()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json");


            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user", 
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
        }

        // Create Google Sheets API service.
        var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
        });

        return service;
    }
```

But with this code the C# application open a browser to ask the user to login in his google account.

I need to have access via API, so it will be transparent to the user.
I already have the API key, but I don't know how to use and I don't find any documentation on Google sites.

Can you help me with some kind of example to read a simple column?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/v3/) is the documentation for the API.
It also covers authorization.

Comment: Hi Maurice, I can't find a working example with api key in the documentation. Can you post it here?

Comment: My bad, I linked the old API. You can find the description to the API Key here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing

Comment: After you have an API key, your application can append the query parameter key=yourAPIKey to all request URLs.

Comment: I don't understand how to make the request, I always get 403 Unauthorized